# Qt вычисление Sha1

Tags: криптография, qt

```
QByteArray concat;
concat.append(login.toUpper());
concat.append(":");
concat.append(password.toUpper());
qDebug() << concat; // ASD:DSA
QByteArray hash = QCryptographicHash::hash(concat, QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
qDebug() << hash;  // EV<"ii§paIAEO3o5+?
```

Очевидно, что что-то здесь не так. Подскажите где косяк.

Comment: Похоже на SHA1 RAW. Сделайте в хексе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Необходимо брать hash.toHex()